# Screen goes black whenever video is played (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, mp4

I brought a couple of Intel compute sticks (feeble little things) running Ubuntu 14.04 to play a couple of mp4 videos on various screens around the office. One works fine and is happily repeating a 4 min corporate presentation video.

The other however is not, whenever I try to play the video on VLC or Firefox, the entire screen goes black. If I pause the video, visuals are restored, leaving me with a still of how far the video has gotten.

I've reinstalled Ubuntu Restricted Extras and VLC but that hasn't helped. There are no propriatary video drivers installed either as its just Intel stuff in there.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Many thanks for any suggestions.